# Angular private in type Platform but not in type

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm a bit confused by the error I am having.

Having upgraded my version of angular to v10 in my project, I am having the following issue:

This was my code that was working fine before:

```
import { Platform } from '@angular/cdk/platform';

const platform: Platform = {
            isBrowser: false,
            TRIDENT: false,
            EDGE: false,
            WEBKIT: false,
            IOS: false,
            BLINK: false,
            FIREFOX: false,
            SAFARI: false,
            ANDROID: false
        }
```

I was doing the above in a `beforeEach` within a spec test and passing through the value of `platform` to a function.

However, I then received the error:

```
Property '_platformId' is missing in type '{ isBrowser: false; TRIDENT: false; EDGE: false; WEBKIT: false; IOS: false; BLINK: false; FIREFOX: false; SAFARI: false; ANDROID: false; }' but required in type 'Platform'
```

I figured this must be a new requirement in the newer version of angular so I updated as follows:

```
        const platform: Platform = {
            isBrowser: false,
            TRIDENT: false,
            EDGE: false,
            WEBKIT: false,
            IOS: false,
            BLINK: false,
            FIREFOX: false,
            SAFARI: false,
            ANDROID: false,
            _platformId: null,
        }
```

However, now I get this issue:

```
Property '_platformId' is private in type 'Platform' but not in type '{ isBrowser: false; TRIDENT: false; EDGE: false; WEBKIT: false; IOS: false; BLINK: false; FIREFOX: false; SAFARI: false; ANDROID: false; _platformId: null; }'
```

Is there any way I can solve this issue? Do I have to set `_platformId` somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Platform is a class, not an interface, interfaces can't have private members.

You can create a `Platform` instance either from your contructor parameters:

```
constructor(public platform: Platform) {}
```

or inside your logic:

```
const p = new Platform("platformID");
```

and then set the properties like you tried [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68227304/5819227).

Answer (score 0):

So this 'works' but there surely has to be a tidier way?

```
let platform1 = new Platform(1);
platform1.isBrowser = false;
platform1.TRIDENT = false;
platform1.EDGE = false;
platform1.WEBKIT = false;
platform1.IOS = false;
platform1.BLINK = false;
platform1.FIREFOX = false;
platform1.SAFARI = false;
platform1.ANDROID = false;
```